# How to automatically convert a Fortran90 program whose variables are in double precision into real?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

everyone

I have a Fortran90 program, and the variables are in double precision or complex*16, now I have to write another program whose variables are in real or complex, and all other things are the same as the original program.

The straightforward way is to rewrite every declaration, but I'm wondering if there are other simpler ways to achieve this, I'm using gfortran as the compiler.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want to reduce the precision of all the real and complex variables, or that you want to rewrite their definitions into modern, standard-compliant form ?  If the former don't expect the program to produce the same results, the differences depend on how well the program has been written.  If the latter, global-search-and-replace with your favourite editor ?

Comment: We need two versions of Fortran90 program, one in IEEE754 double precision and the other in IEEE754 single precision. The double precision version has been written, now I have to write the single version. I read the user's guide of LAPACK, the double precision versions of LAPACK have been generated automatically, using Toolpack/1, my situation is the reverse, so I'm wondering maybe there are ways to automatically convert double precision of my Fortran90 program into single version(I cannot find any information about Toolpack/1)

Comment: If you say "rewrite every declaration" as something difficult, it does not have to be so. Just use search and replace in your text editor possibly with regular expressions or `sed` or `awk` or a similar tool. Definitely use the structure suggested by Bálint Aradi as a final result. For LAPACK it is nice to have a generic interface to the routines, but you may also just replace the S <=> D in the names as well.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the cleanest (althoug not the easiest) way would be to rewrite your program to have adjustable precision for the variables:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: rp = kind(1.0d0)
  real(rp) :: myreal
  complex(rp) :: mycomplex
```

By setting the parameter `rp` (real precision) to `kind(1.0)` instead of `kind(1.0d0)` you can switch from double to single. Alternatively, with fortran 2003 compatible compilers you can also use the names `real64` and `real32` after invoking the `iso_fortan_env` module. (UPDATE: it needs a fortran 2008 compatible compiler, not fortran 2003, see the comment of IanH).

Comment: Itty bitty kinds in ISO_FORTRAN_ENV needs F2008.

Comment: Thanks, Bálint Aradi, I'm wondering if there was a way to convert without too many modifications of the original double precision version.